# How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS in NodeBB using Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, nodebb

I'm using [NodeBB](https://nodebb.org/) on Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache 2.4. I've installed a signed SSL certificate and verified HTTPS is working on my site.

I know how to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS via `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But I have no idea how to go about this in NodeBB. How can I redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS using NodeBB?